# wordpress plugin for database field search

Tags: plugin-recommendation, search

Is there any wordpress plugin to search for people's names in the database?
If i have a column 'name' , i need to provide search functionality over it, give all the matching results for that column. Sentence completion would be even better. I am no PHP programmer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for here. We need to know which table contains the column you're speaking about. This will help determine if you can use native WP functions or if you need to use Wordpress Database Class.

Comment: I created a new table called users which has user name, address.. need to provide a 'search by name' functionality on that table, people should be able to search users.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There's a separate Class as DB layer for this: [The WP User Query Class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query).

If you want to extend the search functionality, a possible option is to alter the query before you output the results on your search.php template. There's a tutorial/how-to over [here](http://flav36rs.com/2010/03/15/extend-wordpress-search-to-include-custom-post-meta/).

If you need additional fields for your users, you can extend the profile easily. See [here](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields) for a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Kaiser.. Is there any way without writing any php? something which is plug and play?

Comment: You really need to hire a developer if you want custom functionality without any sort of coding.

Comment: I have to double @BrianFegter comment.

Comment: @KaKa Btw: Have you already searched the official repository?